# Convert np.ndarray to np.array in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have some data loaded as a np.ndarray and need to convert it to a np.array.

Is there an easy/quick way of doing this without having to re-load the data in a different way?

All the information I can find in tutorials seems to refer to one type of array or the other, but not how to change data from one to the other.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are the same: `numpy.array` is a function that constructs an object of type `numpy.ndarray`.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.ndarray
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> numpy.array
<built-in function array>
>>> numpy.array([])
array([], dtype=float64)
>>> isinstance(numpy.array([]), numpy.ndarray)
True
```