# How to convert ndarray to array?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm using pandas.Series and np.ndarray.

The code is like this

```
>>> t
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
>>> pandas.Series(t)
Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
>>>
```

And I trie to convert it into 1-dimensional array:

```
>>> tt = t.reshape((1,-1))
>>> tt
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

tt is still multi-dimensional since there are double '['.

**So how do I get a really convert ndarray into array?**

After searching, [it says they are the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334906/convert-np-ndarray-to-np-array-in-python). However in my situation, they are not working the same.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

An alternative is to use [np.ravel](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
>>> np.zeros((3,3)).ravel()
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

The importance of `ravel` over `flatten` is `ravel` only copies data if necessary and usually returns a view, while `flatten` will always return a copy of the data.

To use reshape to flatten the array:

```
tt = t.reshape(-1)
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [`.flatten`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html):

```
>>> np.zeros((3,3))
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
>>> _.flatten()
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

EDIT: As pointed out, this returns a copy of the input in every case. To avoid the copy, use `.ravel` as suggested by @Ophion.

Comment: `.flatten` returns a copy, not a view, so it should generally not be your first option.

Comment: @Jaime: thanks, I've noted it. (And +1 to Ophion for pointing out `.ravel`...clearly I don't use NumPy enough.)

Answer (score 1):

```
tt = array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])

oneDvector = tt.A1
```

This is the only approach which solved the problem of double brackets, that is conversion to 1D array that nd matrix.