# Error while using Scatter plot: TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
os.chdir("/Users/Jeffin/Desktop")
data =pd.read_csv('ccc.csv')
print(data.shape)

data = data.drop(index=[0])
print(data)

x1 = data.drop(data.columns[0:5],axis=1)
x1= x1.drop(x1.columns[1:25],axis=1)
print(x1)

y1 = data.drop(data.columns[0:12],axis=1)
y1= y1.drop(y1.columns[1:25],axis=1)
print(y1)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
[x_t, x_r, y_t, y_r]=train_test_split(x1,y1,test_size= 0.3,random_state=0)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(x_t,y_t)
pre = model.predict(x_r)
print(pre.shape)
acc = model.score(x_t,y_t)
plt.scatter(x_t,y_t)
```

I am getting error in the last line as

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:
  File "Clot.py", line 2862, in scatter

...
...

 for val in OrderedDict.fromkeys(data)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Being new to ML help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the line causing the error `for val in OrderedDict.fromkeys(data)` isn't in the code you posted, please edit the question to show the actual code, or post the full error traceback

Comment: It is probably because shape of x_t and y_t doesn't match. What are their shapes?

Comment: From the docs: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html. This requires an array type, but you have ndarray, which is a multidimensional represenation of array. So, try to convert your ndarray to array like type. See for example this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18200052/how-to-convert-ndarray-to-array